# jsTree : how can i search with id in jsTree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

In jsTree, I have many node with same name but different id. So, i want to search  a node with
id with **search** plugin.

Please help me to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer this url: http://www.jstree.com/documentation/search. check demos.

Answer (score 1):

at current version (3.3), you can handle results of search with option 'search_callback'

```
$(element).jstree({
    'search': {
        'search_callback': function(searchValue, node){
            return node.id == searchValue;
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The current jstree version supports only search by node title! It works by `pattern matching`. There is no way you can use the `search plugin` to search based on the id unless you write your own!